# Elegant numpy array shifting and NaN filling?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have a specific performance problem here. I'm working with meteorological forecast timeseries, which I compile into a numpy 2d array such that

- dim0 = time at which forecast series starts
- dim1 = the forecast horizon, eg. 0 to 120 hrs

Now, I would like dim0 to have hourly intervals, but some sources yield forecasts only every N hours. As an example, say N=3 and the time step in dim1 is M=1 hour. Then I get something like

```
12:00  11.2  12.2  14.0  15.0  11.3  12.0
13:00  nan   nan   nan   nan   nan   nan
14:00  nan   nan   nan   nan   nan   nan
15:00  14.7  11.5  12.2  13.0  14.3  15.1
```

But of course there is information at 13:00 and 14:00 as well, since it can be filled in from the 12:00 forecast run. So I would like to end up with something like this:

```
12:00  11.2  12.2  14.0  15.0  11.3  12.0
13:00  12.2  14.0  15.0  11.3  12.0  nan
14:00  14.0  15.0  11.3  12.0  nan   nan
15:00  14.7  11.5  12.2  13.0  14.3  15.1
```

What is the fastest way to get there, assuming dim0 is in the order of 1e4 and dim1 in the order of 1e2? Right now I'm doing it row by row but that is very slow:

```
nRows, nCols = dat.shape
if N >= M:
    assert(N % M == 0)  # must have whole numbers
    for i in range(1, nRows):
        k = np.array(np.where(np.isnan(self.dat[i, :])))
        k = k[k < nCols - N]  # do not overstep
        self.dat[i, k] = self.dat[i-1, k+N]
```

I'm sure there must be a more elegant way to do this? Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind explaining it differently, I got lost in the sentence "But of course ...". How are the different sources represented in the array? Do dim0 mean rows and dim1=dimension1=columns?

Comment: @elyase: The numbers are getting shifted down and to the left, because, for example, if the forecast is 12.2 one hour from now (at 12:00), then in an hour the forecast will be 12.2 zero hours from then (at 13:00).

Answer (score 6):

Behold, the power of boolean indexing!!!

```
def shift_nans(arr) :
    while True:
        nan_mask = np.isnan(arr)
        write_mask = nan_mask[1:, :-1]
        read_mask = nan_mask[:-1, 1:]
        write_mask &= ~read_mask
        if not np.any(write_mask):
            return arr
        arr[1:, :-1][write_mask] = arr[:-1, 1:][write_mask]
```

I think the naming is self explanatory of what is going on. Getting the slicing right is a pain, but it seems to be working:

```
In [214]: shift_nans_bis(test_data)
Out[214]: 
array([[ 11.2,  12.2,  14. ,  15. ,  11.3,  12. ],
       [ 12.2,  14. ,  15. ,  11.3,  12. ,   nan],
       [ 14. ,  15. ,  11.3,  12. ,   nan,   nan],
       [ 14.7,  11.5,  12.2,  13. ,  14.3,  15.1],
       [ 11.5,  12.2,  13. ,  14.3,  15.1,   nan],
       [ 15.7,  16.5,  17.2,  18. ,  14. ,  12. ]])
```

And for timings:

```
tmp1 = np.random.uniform(-10, 20, (1e4, 1e2))
nan_idx = np.random.randint(30, 1e4 - 1,1e4)
tmp1[nan_idx] = np.nan
tmp1 = tmp.copy()

import timeit

t1 = timeit.timeit(stmt='shift_nans(tmp)',
                   setup='from __main__ import tmp, shift_nans',
                   number=1)
t2 = timeit.timeit(stmt='shift_time(tmp1)', # Ophion's code
                   setup='from __main__ import tmp1, shift_time',
                   number=1)

In [242]: t1, t2
Out[242]: (0.12696346416487359, 0.3427293070417363)
```

Comment: You can update the nan_mask using `nan_mask[1:,:-1]^=write_mask` so you only have to calculate `np.isnan(arr)` once. The downside is your write_mask has to be copied so that it does not change the values in nan_mask. Can be much faster or slightly slower depending on the maximum iterations required.

Comment: Thanks you all for your smart solutions! I knew there had to be many ways to do this and it seems we have now sampled a good fraction of them... I'll go for this one, that should solve my problem nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Slicing your data using `a=yourdata[:,1:]`.

```
def shift_time(dat):

    #Find number of required iterations
    check=np.where(np.isnan(dat[:,0])==False)[0]
    maxiters=np.max(np.diff(check))-1

    #No sense in iterations where it just updates nans
    cols=dat.shape[1]
    if cols<maxiters: maxiters=cols-1

    for iters in range(maxiters):
        #Find nans
        col_loc,row_loc=np.where(np.isnan(dat[:,:-1]))

        dat[(col_loc,row_loc)]=dat[(col_loc-1,row_loc+1)]


a=np.array([[11.2,12.2,14.0,15.0,11.3,12.0],
[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
[14.7,11.5,12.2,13.0,14.3,15.]])

shift_time(a)
print a

[[ 11.2  12.2  14.   15.   11.3  12. ]
 [ 12.2  14.   15.   11.3  12.    nan]
 [ 14.   15.   11.3  12.    nan   nan]
 [ 14.7  11.5  12.2  13.   14.3  15. ]]
```

To use your data as is or it can be changed slightly to take it directly, but this seems to be a clear way to show this:

```
shift_time(yourdata[:,1:]) #Updates in place, no need to return anything.
```

Using tiago's test:

```
tmp = np.random.uniform(-10, 20, (1e4, 1e2))
nan_idx = np.random.randint(30, 1e4 - 1,1e4)
tmp[nan_idx] = np.nan

t=time.time()
shift_time(tmp,maxiter=1E5)
print time.time()-t

0.364198923111 (seconds)
```

If you are really clever you should be able to get away with a single `np.where`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
import numpy as np

def shift_time(dat):
    NX, NY = dat.shape
    for i in range(NY):
        x, y = np.where(np.isnan(dat))
        xr = x - 1
        yr = y + 1
        idx = (xr >= 0) & (yr < NY)
        dat[x[idx], y[idx]] = dat[xr[idx], yr[idx]]
    return
```

Now with some test data:

```
In [1]: test_data = array([[ 11.2,  12.2,  14. ,  15. ,  11.3,  12. ],
                           [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
                           [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
                           [ 14.7,  11.5,  12.2,  13. ,  14.3,  15.1],
                           [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
                           [ 15.7,  16.5,  17.2,  18. ,  14. ,  12. ]])
In [2]: shift_time(test_data)
In [3]: print test_data
Out [3]: 
array([[ 11.2,  12.2,  14. ,  15. ,  11.3,  12. ],
       [ 12.2,  14. ,  15. ,  11.3,  12. ,   nan],
       [ 14. ,  15. ,  11.3,  12. ,   nan,   nan],
       [ 14.7,  11.5,  12.2,  13. ,  14.3,  15.1],
       [ 11.5,  12.2,  13. ,  14.3,  15.1,   nan],
       [ 15.7,  16.5,  17.2,  18. ,  14. ,  12. ]])
```

And testing with a (1e4, 1e2) array:

```
In [1]: tmp = np.random.uniform(-10, 20, (1e4, 1e2))
In [2]: nan_idx = np.random.randint(30, 1e4 - 1,1e4)
In [3]: tmp[nan_idx] = nan
In [4]: time test3(tmp)
CPU times: user 1.53 s, sys: 0.06 s, total: 1.59 s
Wall time: 1.59 s
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of this pad,roll,roll combo essentially does what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan as nan

# Startup array
A = np.array([[11.2, 12.2, 14.0, 15.0, 11.3, 12.0],
              [nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
              [nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
              [14.7, 11.5, 12.2, 13.0, 14.3, 15.1]])

def pad_nan(v, pad_width, iaxis, kwargs):
    v[:pad_width[0]]  = nan
    v[-pad_width[1]:] = nan
    return v

def roll_data(A):
    idx = np.isnan(A)
    A[idx] = np.roll(np.roll(np.pad(A,1, pad_nan),1,0), -1, 1)[1:-1,1:-1][idx]
    return A

print A
print roll_data(A)
print roll_data(A)
```

The output gives:

```
[[ 11.2  12.2  14.   15.   11.3  12. ]
 [  nan   nan   nan   nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan   nan   nan   nan]
 [ 14.7  11.5  12.2  13.   14.3  15.1]]

[[ 11.2  12.2  14.   15.   11.3  12. ]
 [ 12.2  14.   15.   11.3  12.    nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan   nan   nan   nan]
 [ 14.7  11.5  12.2  13.   14.3  15.1]]

[[ 11.2  12.2  14.   15.   11.3  12. ]
 [ 12.2  14.   15.   11.3  12.    nan]
 [ 14.   15.   11.3  12.    nan   nan]
 [ 14.7  11.5  12.2  13.   14.3  15.1]]
```

Everything is pure numpy so it should be extremely fast each iteration. However I'm not sure of the cost of creating a padded array and running the multiple iterations, if you try it let me know the results!

Comment: I think many iterations of this will kill the performance. I tested it using a similar setup to my answer (running NY iterations), and it in my system it took 33.85s for an array shape of (10000, 100), about 20x slower than my solution (which is similar to that of Ophion).